# Issue related to adding component into another in Angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

i have web application with Angular 6.

I have following structure:

```
src
 -app
   -auth  - folder
       -auth.component.html               
       -auth.component.scss
       -auth.component.ts 
       -auth.module.ts 
   -car-details  - folder
       -binning-table  - folder
             -binning-table.component.html
             -binning-table.component.ts
             -binning-table.component.scss
       -car-detail.component.html
       -car-detail.component.ts
       -car-detail.component.scss
       -car-detail.module.ts
    -import-binning   - folder
        -import-binning.component.html
        -import-binning.component.scss
        -import-binning.component.ts
   -app.component.html
   -app.component.scss
   -app.component.ts
   -app.module.ts
```

now `car-detail module` registerd into `auth.module.ts` and `authModule` is registered into `app.module`.

i want to load `binning-table component` into `import-binning.html`

what changes should make in order to load one component into another.

what kind of connection i need registerd in which module

Thanks

Comment: import-binning.component is part of which module?

Comment: its in app.module

Comment: @user144271 try <app-binning-table>?

Comment: Have you exported 'binning-table.component' in 'car-detail.module'. you need to export 'car-details.module' in  'auth.module.ts'.

Comment: yes i have exported, then what i need to do ?

Comment: if you import 'binning-table component' inside 'import-binning.component'. are you getting any error?

Comment: yes.. following error   Type BinningTableComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: CarDetailModule and ImportBinningModule! Please consider moving BinningTableComponent to a higher module that imports CarDetailModule and ImportBinningModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes BinningTableComponent then import that NgModule in CarDetailModule and ImportBinningModule.

Comment: Updated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't register a module we import it where ever required, a module can be imported into multiple modules(e.g shared module).

But We can only declare a component in one module, if we need to use the same component in another module, we export it from the same module and import that module into the module where it is required

e.g if we have a component by name A declared in module name module1, and if we need to use the same component in some other module ie module 2, we do something like this.

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
 Acomponent
],
exports: [
 Acomponent
 ]
})
export class Module1 {}

@NgModule({
 imports: [Module1]
})
export class Module2
```

By using the above syntax we can use AComponent in module1 as well as module2, 
generally, the components which are shared throughout the applications we generally put them in the shared module.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring 'BinningTableComponent' inside 'app.module.ts', you need to declare it inside 'car-details.module.ts'. You need to include this same component 'BinningTableComponent' as part of exports array.

So car-details.module=>auth.module=>app.module. You can access 'BinningTableComponent' inside app.component.ts.

Refer the stackblitz code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivnodq